# MBP becomes very hot after using Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-mountain-lion

Hardware: MBP early 2011 version

OS: Mountain lion

App: Xcode 4.5.2

Problem: Every time when I start Xcode, 2 or 3 processes called "git" start running. But when I quit Xcode the "git" process won't quit and are still using a lot of CPU. Then the computer becomes quite hot and the battery gets drained very quickly. If I manually kill these processes the problem is gone. I tried to reinstall Xcode several times but the problem comes back every time.

It drives me crazy. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I hear git, I think of the versioning software, like Subversion. This is XCode, so it's likely that this is a module in xcode to connect to a git-server. Maybe you can remove this module?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410129/tutorial-on-git-with-xcode

Thinking about it, it sounds more like xcode starts up a local git-server by itself, and that git-server doesn't stop after xcode stops.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to stop this git-server once and forever?

Comment: I don't even remember I have installed git server.

Comment: Wow. Finally I got rid of this "git". First I have to remove all git repositories from Xcode organizers. Then remove .git folders. After a restart a quiet computer is back. Thanks for your help.